# Почему выдаётся ошибка и как её исправить [c++]

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main();{
char str[];
cout "Enter the pipe";
cin >> str;
cout << str <<;

return 0;

}
```

суть кода в том чтобы пользователь написал любое слово/ цифру/ букву и т.п но вылезает ошибка `[Error] expected unqualified-id before '{' token`

Comment: я выделил 100 мест но ошибка осталась

Comment: Нужно убрать точку с запятой после `main` и выделить память для `str`. Убрать `<<` после `str` и добавить перед `"Enter the pipe"`

Comment: +reputation помогло

Comment: ого, даже кому то вопрос  понравился

Answer (score 2):

Что за детский сад:

```
int main();{
```

Уберите `;` после `main()` и будет Вам счастье.
Да и в строке

```
cout << str <<;
```

Последний символ `<<` лишний. А вообще читайте комментарий EOF, он все Ваши ошибки выделил.